# RoR Difficulty accessing params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I have an edit page with the following code, basically a dropdown and button that calls update.

```
  <% form_tag('switch_car', :method => :put) do%>
<div class="field">
    <label>Car Name:</label>
    <%= select("params", ":id", @available_cars.collect {|v| [v.name, v.id]})%>
</div>
<div>
    <%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The server reads like the params is being set:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"8vHXrnICaOKrGns6FfMUcd/dWo5kpNKpA8F5l5ozRkY=", "params"=>{":id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Switch Car"}
```

However, when I put the params into a session I get nothing.  It seems to be always nil.  Not sure what I am doing wrong?  Here is code in the controller.

```
     def update
    if params[:id]
      session[:car_info_id] = params[:id]
      redirect_to entry_url
    else
      redirect_to switch_car_path
    end

  end
```

It always gets redirected to the switch_car_path so I am assuming params[:id] is always nil.  When I put if params[:id] == nil it goes to the entry_url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answer would work, this is probably what you'd want to be doing (using `select_tag(:id)` will automatically add an `:id` key/value to the `params` hash):

```
<% form_tag('switch_car', :method => :put) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Car Name:</label>
    <%= select_tag(:id, options_from_collection_for_select(@available_cars, "id", "name")) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then you can easily access `params[:id]` in the controller.

Comment: Thanks this is a little cleaner than the below answer so I will use this.  Both did work though.

Answer (score 3):

you want `params[:params][":id"]`

Alternatively, you could put this in your view:

```
<%= select("car_info", "id", @available_cars.collect {|v| [v.name, v.id]})%>
```

And then in your controller:

```
if params[:car_info][:id]
```

Comment: Thanks this answer worked but the above is a little cleaner so I will use that.  I wish I could vote it up but I don't have enough rep yet.  Thanks again.